# can't find error Invalid read of size 4 valgrind

Tags: c++, boost, valgrind

I have implemented multitask application in c++. Producer push on queue, and consumer get elements from queue. Sometimes my application crashed. Could someone help me with this problem. sf

Valgrind output:

```
    ==10769== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==10769== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==10769== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==10769== Command: ./tachyon -s /HOME_ann/BII/biidurgak/test_new_tachyon/Tachyon_v5_improvedQueryTime/settings_smallNR
    ==10769== 
    ==10769== Thread 5:
    ==10769== Invalid read of size 4
    ==10769==    at 0x342669C9DE: std::string::assign(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
    ==10769==    by 0x42E01A: std::pair::operator=(std::pair const&) (stl_pair.h:152)
    
    ==10769==    by 0x42B27A: boost::lockfree::detail::ringbuffer_base >::pop(std::pair&, std::pair*, unsigned
     long) (spsc_queue.hpp:154)
    ==10769==    by 0x428719: boost::lockfree::detail::compile_time_sized_ringbuffer, 2ul>::pop(std::pair&) (spsc_queue.hpp:305)
    ==10769==    by 0x425DEA: boost::lockfree::spsc_queue, boost::lockfree::capacity, boost::parameter::void_>::pop(std::pair&) (spsc_queue.hpp:572)
    ==10769==    by 0x41BE16: findInDatabase() (Tachyon.cpp:103)
    ==10769==    by 0x4351D4: boost::detail::thread_data::run() (thread.hpp:117)
    ==10769==    by 0x4E53D01: thread_proxy (in /HOME_ann/BII/biidurgak/test_new_tachyon/boost_install/boost_1_55_0/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0)
    ==10769==    by 0x342120673C: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so)
    ==10769==    by 0x34206D3D1C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
    ==10769==  Address 0xfffffffffffffff8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
    ==10769== 
    ==10769== 
    ==10769== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==10769==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8
    ==10769==    at 0x342669C9DE: std::string::assign(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
    ==10769==    by 0x42E01A: std::pair::operator=(std::pair const&) (stl_pair.h:152)
    ==10769==    by 0x42B27A: boost::lockfree::detail::ringbuffer_base >::pop(std::pair&, std::pair*, unsigned long) (spsc_queue.hpp:154)
    ==10769==    by 0x428719: boost::lockfree::detail::compile_time_sized_ringbuffer, 2ul>::pop(std::pair&) (spsc_queue.hpp:305)
    ==10769==    by 0x425DEA: boost::lockfree::spsc_queue, boost::lockfree::capacity, boost::parameter::void_>::pop(std::pair&) (spsc_queue.hpp:572)
    ==10769==    by 0x41BE16: findInDatabase() (Tachyon.cpp:103)
    ==10769==    by 0x4351D4: boost::detail::thread_data::run() (thread.hpp:117)
    ==10769==    by 0x4E53D01: thread_proxy (in /HOME_ann/BII/biidurgak/test_new_tachyon/boost_install/boost_1_55_0/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0)
    ==10769==    by 0x342120673C: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so)
    ==10769==    by 0x34206D3D1C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
    ==10769==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
    ==10769==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
    ==10769==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
    ==10769==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
    ==10769==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
    ==10769== 
    ==10769== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==10769==     in use at exit: 219,895,341 bytes in 4,598,508 blocks
    ==10769==   total heap usage: 36,680,650 allocs, 32,082,142 frees, 1,474,244,383 bytes allocated
    ==10769== 
    ==10769== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==10769==    definitely lost: 1,904 bytes in 2 blocks
    ==10769==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==10769==      possibly lost: 184,232,229 bytes in 4,598,462 blocks
    ==10769==    still reachable: 35,661,208 bytes in 44 blocks
    ==10769==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==10769== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
    ==10769== 
    ==10769== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

Producer:

```cpp
    void producer(string file) {
            ifstream query(file.c_str());
            string description = "";
            string sequence = "";

            string line;
            while (getline(query, line)) {
                //read description
                if (line == "") continue;
                if (line.at(0) == '>') {
                    if (sequence != "") {
                        pair<string, string> a = make_pair(description, sequence);
                        while (!queue.push(a))
                            ;
                        sequence = "";
                    }
                    description = line.substr(1);
                } else {
                    sequence += line;
                }
            }

            if (sequence != "" && description != "") {
        pair<string, string> a = make_pair(description, sequence);
        while (!queue.push(a))
            ;
    }
}
```

In the consumer I have this:

```cpp
 void Consumer(void) {
             pair<string, string>element;
             //part of code 
        
             while(queue.pop(element)){  //Line 103 in Tachyon.cpp 
                string queryDescription = element.first;
                string sequence = element.second;
        
                //Part of code 
             }
          
          }
```

Queue is the global variable:

```cpp
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<pair<string, string>, boost::lockfree::capacity<2> > queue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables, multiple threads (I assume), one reading and another thread writing - you need a synchronization object like mutex or critical section.

Pseudocode:

```
// Consumer
loop-begin;
Lock();
get-item-into-local-variable
Unlock();
process-local-variable-item;
loop-end

// Producer
void AddItem(item)
{
Lock();
Add-item-into-queue
Unlock();
}
```

Comment: I use queue from boost library, this queue is thread safe, and I don't need mutex in code.

Comment: Well.. then it invalidates my answer, I overlooked it. I don't know about boost library. May be there are set of methods which are not concurrent safe. I guess `queue::pop`

Comment: No, all methods are concurrent safe.

Comment: Yes, thread safe. But I read that only one thread (at particular time) is allowed to push/pop. Also check if items are there in queue before calling `pop`.

Comment: As you can see in this example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html
we can use more threads for pop and push without mutex